# Perl script that checks rotated log files

Tags: perl

There is a web server running multiple websites with configured daily log files rotation.

Task: create a perl script that checks a list of current log files in source directory and compare it with a list of rotated log files in another dir. Script must print a name of log file, if one the yesterday's log was not rotated.

Source dir example:

```
ls -l /var/log/httpd/logs/*log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 20 00:01 /var/log/httpd/logs/access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 483652 May 20 12:54 /var/log/httpd/logs/othersite.com_80-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 305 May 20 11:51 /var/log/httpd/logs/othersite.com_80-error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 20 00:01 /var/log/httpd/logs/error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46222 May 20 12:45 /var/log/httpd/logs/www.site.com_8880-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 20 00:01 /var/log/httpd/logs/www.site.com_8880-error.log
```

dir with a rotated logs:

```
ls -l /var/log/httpd/logs/completed/|grep 2014-05-19
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20 May 20 00:01 access.log.2014-05-19.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 107244 May 20 00:01 othersite.com_80-access.log.2014-05-19.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9991 May 20 00:01 www.site.com_8880-access.log.2014-05-19.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20 May 20 00:01 www.site.com_8880-error.log.2014-05-19.gz
```

In this case two yesterday's log files are absent\were not rotated:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 483652 May 20 12:54 /var/log/httpd/logs/othersite.com_80-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 305 May 20 11:51 /var/log/httpd/logs/othersite.com_80-error.log
```

Looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: The problem is that my Perl knowledge is very poor and I have no idea how it should be done. I can easily do it with a Bash script, but task requires Perl. That's it.

Comment: I would start by learning perl, then.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `glob <>` on the source directory and put in a hash key.  You put the size of the log or date in the value of the hash. Then go to the destination directory and do the same thing - read the files and as you loop, check to see if you have the file in you hash.  You can compare the size and date also.  if you don't have it, copy it.

Comment: Thanks for fast response! Could you give me more or less working example? Size of rotated log file is not relevant since size of original log file can be 0. So the main thing is to verify that for every log file in source dir, there is a rotated log file in destination dir.